# Agda. Pattern matching on characters

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, agda

I've tried to implement my version of "sprintf" function (which constructs a string from a format string a number of arguments of different types), but failed. Same technique worked in Idris.

```
module Printf where
open import Agda.Builtin.List
open import Agda.Builtin.Char
open import Agda.Builtin.String
open import Agda.Builtin.Float
open import Agda.Builtin.Int

data Format : Set where
   TChar : Char → Format → Format
   TString : Format → Format
   TFloat : Format → Format
   TInt : Format → Format
   TEnd : Format

parseFormat : List Char → Format
parseFormat ('%' :: 's' :: rest) = TString (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat ('%' :: 'f' :: rest) = TFloat (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat ('%' :: 'd' :: rest) = TInt    (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat ('%' :: '%' :: rest) = TChar '%' (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat (x :: rest)          = TChar x (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat []                   = TEnd
```

But I get this error by the compiler:

```
Could not parse the left-hand side parseFormat ('%' :: 's' :: rest)
Operators used in the grammar:
  None
when scope checking the left-hand side
parseFormat ('%' :: 's' :: rest) in the definition of parseFormat
```

Is it possible to pattern-match on characters like '1', 't', 'O' in Agda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no constructor of `List` named `_::_`. What you meant to use is `_∷_`. Replacing all occurrences of `::` with `∷` fixes the problem:

```
parseFormat : List Char → Format
parseFormat ('%' ∷ 's' ∷ rest) = TString (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat ('%' ∷ 'f' ∷ rest) = TFloat (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat ('%' ∷ 'd' ∷ rest) = TInt    (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat ('%' ∷ '%' ∷ rest) = TChar '%' (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat (x ∷ rest)         = TChar x (parseFormat rest)
parseFormat []                 = TEnd
```